# How to fix 'Cannot use 'import.meta' outside a module' in Vue2 with vite when running test

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, jestjs, vite

I'm converting my vue2 app from `vue-cli-service` to use `vit` everything is working well but the tests fails with this error:

`Jest encountered an unexpected token

```
Jest failed to parse a file. This happens e.g. when your code or its dependencies use non-standard JavaScript syntax, or when Jest is not configured to support such syntax.

Out of the box Jest supports Babel, which will be used to transform your files into valid JS based on your Babel configuration.

By default "node_modules" folder is ignored by transformers.

Here's what you can do:
 • If you are trying to use ECMAScript Modules, see https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules for how to enable it.
 • If you are trying to use TypeScript, see https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started#using-typescript
 • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
 • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
 • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration
For information about custom transformations, see:
https://jestjs.io/docs/code-transformation

Details:

/home/khaledmoustafa/jumia/MDS/crm/crmt-andromeda/src/components/AppIntro/AppIntro.vue:74
      gID: import.meta.env.VITE_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
                  ^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use 'import.meta' outside a module

  2 | import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
  3 | import { mount, createLocalVue } from '@vue/test-utils'
> 4 | import AppIntro from './AppIntro'
    | ^
  5 | import '@/../tests/windowMock.js'
  6 |
  7 | Vue.use(Vuetify)

  at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/jest-cli/node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1495:14)
  at Object.require (src/components/AppIntro/AppIntro.spec.js:4:1)
`
```

and I tried to use some packages to solve it like `babel-plugin-transform-import-meta` but it doesn't work, and this is my `jest.confg` file:

```
module.exports = {
  moduleFileExtensions: ['js', 'jsx', 'json', 'vue'],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.vue$': 'vue-jest',
    '^.+\\js$': 'babel-jest'
  },
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^@/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/$1'
  },
  snapshotSerializers: ['jest-serializer-vue'],
  testMatch: ['**/*.spec.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)'],
  testURL: 'http://localhost/',
  reporters: ['default', 'jest-junit'],
  collectCoverage: true,
  collectCoverageFrom: [
    'src/**/*.{js,vue}',
    '!src/components/**/*.{js,vue}',
    '!src/*',
    '!src/router/*',
    '!src/plugins/**',
    '!**/*.stories.js',
    '!**/node_modules/**'
  ],
  coverageReporters: ['html', 'text-summary'],
  transformIgnorePatterns: ['<rootDir>/node_modules/.+.(js|jsx)$']
}
```

and this is `babel.config.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset'],
  plugins: ['babel-plugin-transform-import-meta']
}
```

if any one faced this and have any solution?